# Why an ideal gas expands in the 2nd step of carnot's cycle/engine?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

In the 2nd step of carnot's cycle, when the gas cylinder is kept under an adiabatic condition, it expands and the temperature falls.
My question is
why does the gas spend it's internal energy to expand?Since it's internal energy is not changed from the beginning as the entire heat gained in the 1st step of isothermal expansion is spent as work done.

Comment: In the 2nd step, the gas does work on its surroundings.  This is done by gradually lowering the pressure that the surrounding present to the gas.  In this way, the gas does work on its surroundings and, in the absence of additing heat to the gas, its internal energy must decrease.

Comment: That's my question. Why the gas has to spend any energy? It can remain in the same condition without spending any internal energy.

Comment: Because you are dropping the external pressure on the gas.

Comment: @Hawkingo Ať molecular level, when gas is expanding, the molecules reflected by the container walls have the mean kinetic energy lower than the molecules  approaching the walls. The macroeffect is the gas is cooling down.

Comment: @Hawkingo in order to return on a isothermal compression and do net work in the cycle, you need to lower the temperature of the gas after the isothermal expansion. The adiabatic expansion is needed to accomplish that task.

Comment: But there was no net increase the gas internal energy as the whole heat/energy received during the isothermal expansion was spent on the expansion.

Comment: @Hawkingo yes the heat in equals the work done by the gas so there is no change in internal energy after the isothermal expansion. But the whole idea here is to produce net work over a complete cycle. That means after the expansion we need to find a way to return the system to its original state while doing net work over the cycle. How would you propose to do that without the adiabatic expansion following the isothermal expansion?